# Is there a Sandbox & AppleStore savvy way to put the machine to sleep / shutdown programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos

The problems I encounter:

- `AppleScript` via "`System Events`" is not possible (no scripting entitlement possible due to lacking `SDEF` in `System Events`)
- NSTask to perform a pmset command also not possible due to sandboxing...
- using `IOPMSchedulePowerEvent` requires "root" privileges, so also not possible

Funnily, running an `NSAppleScript` with "do shell script 'pmset sleepnow'" does work, at least on my local machine. But I'm skeptical wether this will pass the `AppStore` check.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you vote this question down, would you please leave a comment telling me why you find the question stupid/inappropriate or even leave another hint? Please...